# Highcharts: Change histogram xaxis range

Tags: highcharts, histogram

I recently discovered highcharts, and it seems like it is pretty cool stuff. But so far, I can not get the histogram working beyond the most basic functionality:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram

I want to show the data of live experiment, and users are allowed to enter values between 0 and 100. Therefore, I would like to force the histogram width to that range. But when I add

```
xAxis:{
    min: 0,
    max: 100
}
```

My chart disappears completely. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your configuration or a jsfiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: Posted demo with min and max works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tke8g0dr/ - maybe you accidentally removed secondary yAxis, or just like in the question, you use `xAxis`, but this should be `yAxis`? ;)

Comment: Should the link be an example of it working? Because it seems to me, it clearly does not. The xAxis has max:100, but goes to 120 ....